# Python port scanner will not return the banner

Tags: python

I've seen many tutorials on ports returning the banners (the services they are using) but mine won't show it. Any help? I just want to return the service that the port is using.

```
import socket


s = socket.socket()

def re_banner(ip, port):
    try:
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024).strip()
        return banner
    except socket.error:
        pass
    except:
        raise



def main():
    ip = raw_input("Please enter the IP: ")
    for port in range(1,1000):
        banner = re_banner(ip,port)
        if banner:
            print '[+]' + ip + '/' + str(port) + ' : ' + banner.strip()

main()
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that any of the services to which you're trying to connect actually return a banner of some sort (e.g., by connecting to them manually using something like `nc`)?

Comment: If possible (if you're not in some work environment), please upgrade yourself to Python 3 :)

Comment: You are silencing `socket.error`s. Try to remove that `except` and see if it gives you any information

Comment: Why are you reusing the same socket `s`? I'd expect it to fail because it's already connected on every iteration after the first.

Comment: @Tomerikoo It didn't work with just the except, it didnt give me anything and i've been playing around with it.